# How can I import a json as a dict?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm working with a json file in Python and I wanted to convert it into a dict.

This is what my file looks like:

```
[
  {
    "label": "Label",
    "path": "/label-path",
    "image": "icon.svg",
    "subcategories": [
      {
        "title": "Main Title",
        "categories": {
          "column1": [
            {
              "label": "Label Title",
              "path": "/Desktop/Folder"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
   }
 ]
```

(sorry about the identation)

So this is what I did:

```
import json
# Opening JSON file 
f = open('file.json') 

# returns JSON object as  
# a dictionary 
data = json.load(f)
```

However, data is now a list, not a dict. I tried to think about how can I convert it to a dict, but (I) not sure how to do this; (II) isn't there a way of importing the file already as a dict?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your data get's imported as  list, because in your JSON file the main structure is an Array (squared brackets), which is comparable to a list in Python.

If you want just inner dict you can do

```
data = json.load(f)[0]
```

Comment: should I delete the question? not sure if I broke any rules (I got a downvote)

Comment: @dekio No you didn't break any rules. Somebody (presumably) thought it was low quality but it looks like someone else took the opposite view and voted it up. In any case, it is not a good idea to delete a question that has been answered, out of fairness to the user(s) who answered it.

Comment: By the way, you could do: `data, = json.load(f)`. This will mean that if your outer list unexpectedly contains more than one element, then it will give an error rather than silently ignore everything after the first one. (This is multiple assignment syntax using a 1-element tuple.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure, but I would think, in a dictionary, you would need a key and a value, so in this example, i'm creating a list for labels/images and then creating a dictionary.

```
# ***** Create List *****
list_label=[]
list_image=[]

# ***** Iterate Json *****
for i in data:
    list_label.append(str(i['label']))
    list_image.append(i['image'])

# ***** Create Dictionary *****
contents = dict(zip(list_label, list_images))
```